# É seguro usar o novo açúcar sintático para callbacks em Javascript?

Tags: javascript, sintaxe

Esses dias eu estava testando algumas funcionalidades do Javascript no `Google Chrome 50` e percebi que já foi adicionada a `arrow function` para callbacks.

Assim:

```
$.each([1, 2, 3], x => x * 2);

// [2, 4, 6]
```

Antigamente teria que fazer assim:

```
$.each([1, 2, 3], function (x) { return x * 2; })
```

Já podemos usar essa opção seguramente para todos os navegadores (estamos em 2016!), ou ainda terei que esperar mais um pouquinho?

Comment: Podias ter JS nativo em vêz de jQuery :) Quanto menos jQuery melhor :P

Comment: @Sergio foi só um exemplo :D

Comment: Como o @GabrielKatakura falou, ainda não dá pra fazer isso diretamente. Mas você pode usar algo como TypeScript (http://www.typescriptlang.org/) que "compila" para JS nativo, e você pode usar essa sintaxe (além de muitas outras coisas que JS não tem)

Comment: Eu sei, foi meio brincadeira. Mas não sei se junte a tag jQuery se mude os exemplos para `[1, 2, 3].map(x => x * 2);`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Não é seguro. O ECMAScript 6 não está recebendo suporte 100% das features ainda nos navegadores (mesmo os modernos), e mesmo que a última versão do navegador suporte essas features você ira limitar o funcionamento do seu site para esses navegadores. O ideal é programar com features do ECMAScript 5, eu sou adepto nessa ideia, apesar que tem gente que usa outras técnicas para que o código rode até com ECMAScript 3. Tudo depende do seu público, geralmente o suporte para o ECMAScript 5 é o essencial.

Você pode acompanhar o suporte dos navegadores e demais aqui:
http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/

E caso queira mesmo assim usar ECMAScript 6, procure por outras alternativas como Babel, Traceur, Webpack...

Nesse projeto pessoal de um amigo eu fiz recentemente uma branch onde eu rejuvenesci todo o código para ES6. Uso Webpack com Babel nesse projeto e ele funciona em browsers antigos porque o código é transpilado para ES5.

https://github.com/pedrolaxe/js-terminal